# Run Flask single threaded

Tags: python, flask

I presently use system wide mutexes to handle **multiprocessing** in my Flask application.

Due to the GIL, and ultimately that the fact that multiprocessing will already provide me with concurrency, I'd like not to have to worry about **multithreading** in my application as well.

Can I get the Flask development server to run single threaded?

As an aside, if I deploy using Gunicorn, can this do the same (i.e. running *multiple processes*, all of which are *single threaded*)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can run your application with gunicorn using parameters 'workers' and 'threads'

```
gunicorn --workers=5 --threads=1 main:app
```

it means that all workers will be run using single thread

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the source code, I see that Flask has the `--without-threads` parameter, which was added as a result of [this bug report](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/604).

```
. . .
flask run --without-threads . . .
```

As far as I can tell it doesn't appear that the Flask documentation has been updated as a result of the bug fix, so the best documentation can be found in the bug report itself. You can query this property at run-time via `flask.request.is_multithread`.

Answer (score 2):

The flask development server is only single-threaded by default, and yes you can use unicorn with the `workers` and `thread` flags

```
gunicorn --workers=8 --threads=1
```